# how to select, deselect and individual table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Till now i didn't got solution for this,

Two process,

1. i have one button in tableview, if i click the button, display all checkmarks in that section, otherwise none (toggling function).
2. each and every cell is clicked display checkmark, otherwise none.

   i have done first case but i want second also.

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
   NSString *key = [_keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
   NSArray *name = [_names objectForKey:key];
   static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

   if (cell == nil){
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                  reuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];
       cell.textLabel.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   
       if([selectAll.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Deselect All"])
         {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
         }
       else
         {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
         }
   }
  return cell;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
        selectAll.frame = CGRectMake(frame.size.width-90, 5, 86, 30);
    }
    else {
        selectAll.frame = CGRectMake(cmdSwitch.frame.origin.x, 0, 90, 30);
    }
    
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Sel_Check"]==nil)
    {
        [selectAll setTitle:@"Deselect All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        
    }
    else
    {
        if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Sel_Check"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            [selectAll setTitle:@"Deselect All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else if([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Sel_Check"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            [selectAll setTitle:@"Select All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        
    }
    
    selectAll.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
    selectAll.clipsToBounds = YES;
    selectAll.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    selectAll.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    selectAll.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:155.0f/255.0f green:155.0f/255.0f blue:155.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
    selectAll.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    [selectAll setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:43.0f/255.0f green:65.0f/255.0f blue:116.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selectAll setExclusiveTouch:YES];
    [selectAll addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [headerView addSubview:selectAll];
}

return headerView;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 [self checkedCellAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        if([self getCheckedForIndex:indexPath.row]==YES)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
 }
```

// my button function

```
- (void) mySelect:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if([selectAll.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Deselect All"])
{
    [selectAll setTitle:@"Select All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"0" forKey:@"Sel_Check"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
else
{
    [selectAll setTitle:@"Deselect All" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"Sel_Check"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

like this,

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's so complicated? Whenever a cell is selected check to see if all cells are selected.

Comment: You want to select few specific cells by clicking on cells or you just want to select all cells by clicking abouve button and deselect on again clicking it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
    static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [candidates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([self.selectButton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Deselect All"])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should rethink the solution to no. 1 as well. You should have an `NSMutableSet` containing the `NSIndexPath`'s of the selected cells.

When you tap only one cell, add that index path to the set or remove it (if it is already there) then reload the selected row.

When you tap the button above the table, you either add all the existing index paths to the set or empty the set. And then of course call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the condition would change to this:

```
   if([_indexPathsOfSelectedRows containsObject:indexPath])
     {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     }
   else
     {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Steps to follow: 
(1) Make an array (i.e arrCheckedItems) for holding checked cell texts (i.e. @"Five Cents" , @"Ten Cents").
(2) When user select any cell, add that cell's text to arrCheckedItems and when deselect remove that text from array. Then reload the table.
(3) in cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, check cell's text- 



 if([arrCheckedItems containsObject: cell.text])
    {
         // cell.text = @"Five Cents" or @"Ten Cents"
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select or Deselect Cell on tap than :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
}
```

Comment: here i was both button and individual cell toggling function

Comment: And when he scrolls the table, the selection would be gone

Comment: @user3571918 i just gave idea whole implementation is on you :)